# Data event not firing for child_process spawn when custom bash script echos something

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I have been trying to call an custom bash script using child_process spawn module from my node application and I want to capture the stdout echoed by the shell script. I have tried listening to 'data' event but nothing helps. Here is the code:enter code here

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const subprocess = spawn('.\\start_recording.sh', [], {shell:true});

subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  data = data.toString();
  console.log(`Received chunk ${data}`);
});
```

I even tried using:

```
subprocess.stderr.pipe(process.stderr, {end: false});
subprocess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout, {end: false});
```

Still 'data' event not get listened.

Here is my bash script **start_recording.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo something
```

Answer (score -1):

according to nodejs documentation, child_process is asynchronous so try to wrap it in an async function .
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

try this:

```
async ()=>{
    let spawExample = await subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      data = data.toString();
      console.log(`Received chunk ${data}`);
      return data
    });

}
```

Comment: I do not think this is going to solve the problem. Can you pls elaborate?

Comment: @MariamJamal check the answer